# Jupiter Python seaborn heatmap not showing all correlations

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn, correlation

I'm having some trouble with my heatmap plot of the correlation. It's not showing all the columns I'm interested in.

This is my code:

```
sns.set(style="white")
# Compute the correlation matrix
corr = data.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1, vmin=-1, center=0,
        square=True, linewidths=1, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

The code is based on :https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html

[Part of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgpBe.png)

And here is a snip of the data columns missing

[Snip of the columns missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdz8V.png)

The problem, as you can see, is that I'm missing CIVIST_D, F, L 
and I can´t figure out to fix it.

Kind regards 
Christian

Answer (score 6):

Try to increase the size of plot.
It worked for me

```
corr=df.corr()
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
sns.heatmap(corr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps but make sure that the correlation is indeed computed for your desired columns. For example:

```
'CIVIST_D' in corr.index
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment, the last picture "Snip of the columns missing" it is a snip of the concatanated dataset using : data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['CIVIST'])
data.head()